# C++ returning an assignment?

Tags: c++, function, return, variable-assignment

In C++ what does it mean when a function returns an assignment? e.g.

```
int a = ...;
int b = ...;
int some_function(p)
{
    return a = b;
}
```

Comment: It means whoever wrote this line of code was trying to be clever and, in doing so, made the next poor soul who has to read it trip over themselves.

Comment: `a=b` is an expression with the value of `a` after assignment of `b`. The value of that expression is what's returned. Good to recognize this when you see it so it's useful for teaching but never write code like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it performs the assignment, then returns `b`.

This sort of stuff might get flagged by the compiler as an inadvertent bug, usually you'd mean `a == b`, so you may need to deal with that. Doing it as a separate line makes it clear it's intentional.

Comment: It returns the same value than b, but on a semantic level, it returns a, after assigning to a the value of b. This is very important to clarify if there is a line like : return a=b+c;

Comment: @TUIlover Yeah, it returns the evaluated *rvalue* expression. In this trivial case that's just `b`. In a case like `return a = b = c[d] = *e = f(g++)` things get interesting.